# How to disabled right click in ifarme?

Tags: javascript, iframe, vuejs2, right-click, simplemodal

i am using iframe and using those properties style="pointer-events:none;" oncontextmenu="return false" but its not for pdf than why saying for Iframe, which is working fine.

style="pointer-events:none;" oncontextmenu="return false"
i tried those properties but its not working.

Comment: are those styles inside the iframe, think of an iframe is a separate html document (because it is) - you can style the iframe element in the containing document, but you can't style the contained document from the containing document

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.